# Copying a formula which is referencing a string in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the Google sheet extension "Cryptofinance" in my formulas, but I assume this question is valid for all types of formulas created.

So basically the formula requires a string as input which I have successfully referenced using "&indirect", but when I try to copy the formula to the whole column the string part of the formula doesn't change (B3 in below formula).

My formula looks like this: =cryptofinance(""&indirect("B3")&"/USD"; "price"), where B3 is the reference I want to update to B4, B5, B6 etc as I copy the formula.

Any trick I can apply to make this happen so I don't have to manually change B3 to B4, B5, B6, B7 to my 100+ cells?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like solving your problem and answering your question require different answers.

#### Dynamic reference to a cell's address (A1 notation):

To get the cell's address to use it in a context which expects a string, you can use the cell() function.
You can pass the first argument "address", and reference the cell for the second arg.
example:

`=cell("address", A6)`

returns "$A$6"

#### Your task, using the CRYPTOFINANCE(currency_pair, attribute, option) function:

I've installed this plugin to see what it expects for its arguments.
You can achieve the string you want by concatenating the contents of your cell B3, and your base currency "USD" like this:

`=CRYPTOFINANCE(B3 & "/USD","price")`

Which, when copied will offset the cell reference as expected.
This is because the & operator can be used to join any two strings, and the value of the referenced cell will be treated as a string.

Both solutions will work in your case, but the second one removes extraneous function calls which convert your cell to an address to a cell again.